# check a checkbox by clicking a link in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have the folowing code :

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <a href="#" ng-if="!item.children" ng-click="checkItem(item,checkBoxModel)">
        <input class="align"
               ng-click="checkItem(item,checkBoxModel)"
               type="checkbox" ng-checked="master"
               ng-model="checkboxModel"/>     
                 {{ item.title }}                 
     </a>
</li>
```

in my controller i have checkItem function:

```
$scope.checkItem = function(item, checkBoxModel) {
    if (checkBoxModel == undefined || checkBoxModel == true) {
        ....        
        $scope.master=true;
        $scope.checkBoxModel = false;*
    } else {
        ....
        $scope.master = false;
        $scope.checkBoxModel = true;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I click on a link all of the checkboxes are checked.  I just want the checkbox associated to the link to be checked.

Comment: Put it on the `item`, i.e., `item.master = false`

Comment: You are doing an `ng-repeat` but your `ng-model` is the same for all inputs. You need to assign unique models so that the value changed applies to that specific one. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/PQvQ2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
<a href="#" ng-if="!item.children" ng-click="checkItem(item)">
    <input class="align"
           ng-click="checkItem(item)"
           type="checkbox" ng-checked="item.checked"
          />     
             {{ item.title }}                 
 </a>
```

in my controller i change the value of item.checked

Answer (score 1):

Change your app logic. You have to declare a variable for each item. But as i see, you have one for all in the global `$scope` named `master`. The master should have been declared for each item to specify the state of the option box. Then your problem will be solved.

Something like this:

**app.js**

```
$scope.items = [
    {
        name: 'example',
        master: false,
        checkboxModel: false
    },
    {
        name: 'example',
        master: false,
        checkboxModel: false
    }
];

$scope.checkItem = function(item, checkBoxModel) {
    if (checkBoxModel == undefined || checkBoxModel == true) {
        ....        
        $scope.items[item].master = true;
        ...
    } else {
        ....
        $scope.items[item].master = false;
        ...
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<input class="align"
                   ng-click="checkItem(item, checkBoxModel)"
                   type="checkbox" ng-checked="item.master"
                   ng-model="item.checkboxModel"/>
```

Comment: Note: since you're passing in the item `checkItem(item...)`, no need to do `$scope.items[item]` -- just do the work on the `item`

Comment: yep, i know. but both work. it just takes some seconds to remove if someone wants :) btw, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting a value `master` on the controllers `$scope` object, set it on the actual item that you pass in, and set it's `ng-checked="item.master"` and it's `ng-model="item.checkBoxModel"`

```
$scope.checkItem = function(item, checkBoxModel) {
    if (checkBoxModel == undefined || checkBoxModel == true) {
        ....        
        item.master=true;
        item.checkBoxModel = false;
    } else {
        ....
        item.master = false;
        item.checkBoxModel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just realized my answer was basically the same as yours.  Have an upvote.